# Launch firefox on remote server using SSH with a command line parameter

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface, remote-desktop

Is there a way to launch firefox on a remote server using SSH this way ? :

```
ssh username@ip_address [command line]
```

When I run: `ssh username@ip_address -Y (or -X) firefox` (I want to launch **firefox** on the **remote -Ubuntu Desktop-** from my **local -Ubuntu Server**), I get this error: `Error: no display specified`
***Important note***: I want to run this command from an Ubuntu Server  to an Ubuntu Desktop operating system.

Comment: You want the Ubuntu server (A) to issue a command to the Ubuntu Desktop (B) machine to run B's firefox on B's own display, correct?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what i want to do

Comment: Then SSH X forwarding isn't for you, it's helpful if you want to run firefox on B but have it displayed in X11 installed on A. You probably don't even have X11 in A because it's a server

Comment: @Kos yes, you are right, I installed X11 server, but this means I am no longer using Ubuntu Server (but this is not a problem in my case). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use X Forwarding to do that. Make sure that firefox is installed on your server, then from your desktop, run:

```
ssh username@ip_adress -Y [command line]
```

if -Y does not work, you can still use -X instead.

If it's not working, be sure that:

- in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server, `X11Forwarding` is set to `yes`
- in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the client, `ForwardX11` is set to `yes`. Add the line if needed.
- xauth is installed on the server : `sudo apt-get install xauth`

Regards,

Thomas.

Comment: It says: Error: no display specified

Comment: Did you also try the -X option ? Can you provide the output of the command or tell us if you have other errors ?

Comment: Yes, I run it with -Y then with -X options. In both  cases I got only this error message:Error: no display specified

Comment: Also, be sure that `X11Forwarding` is set to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on your server.

Comment: thank you, I just checked and I found it set to yes by default on my ubuntu (both on my local machine and on the server)

Comment: I never had such a situation... Try adding to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the client the following line : `ForwardX11 yes`. Also, install xauth on your server : `sudo apt-get install xauth`

Comment: I installed xauth, I also followed the answers on here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784404/how-can-i-specify-a-display But I get the same error.

Comment: Does it work with other applications (eg xterm) ?

Comment: with xterm it told me: xterm: DISPLAY is not set

Comment: I think when I try to launch firefox on the remote Ubuntu Desktop from my local Ubuntu Server (no GUI), it tries to display Firefox on my local (Ubuntu Server) and not on the remote (Ubuntu Desktop) machine

Comment: Which command line did you use to set `DISPLAY` and start xterm (or firefox) ? Something like this should do the trick : `ssh user@ip -Y 'export DISPLAY=XXXXX && xterm'`

Comment: Ooooh I'm sorry I misread your question... My solution is for launching Firefox on the Server but displaying it on the desktop, but the command has to be executed from the desktop, not from the server.

Comment: I used DISPLAY=paxbox1.paxco.com:0.0, I go no error, but I had no access to the remote machine this way, and the Firefox is not launched on the distant machine either

Comment: The DISPLAY value you used is from the other thread you mentionned. You have to adapt this value to your needs.

Also, I'm not sure to understand : do you want to display Firefox on your desktop while running on your server ? if yes, you have to login on your desktop, then do `ssh username@ip_ubuntu_server -Y firefox`. Then firefox should show up on your desktop.

If you just want to start firefox on your client while connected to the server, just do : `ssh user@ip_desktop -Y 'export DISPLAY=:0.0 && firefox'` (maybe you have to adapt the DISPLAY)
If it's not what you want, can you clarify ? :)

Comment: Fixed by install the xauth you asked me and sudo apt get install xorg openbox

Comment: Why would you install X11 server on one machine to display Firefox on another machine?

Answer (score 1):

This should get you rolling:

```
ssh machine DISPLAY=0:0 firefox
```

Just tried it with two Ubuntu machines.

The syntax `FOO=asdf BAR=fdsa command arg arg2` isn't special to SSH, just sets environment vars for `command`. You need to tell Firefox where's the X11 display - in this case it's the same machine as Firefox. X11 forwarding isn't used because both Firefox and the X11 server are in the same box.

See also https://superuser.com/questions/368530/understanding-x-windows-display-environment-variable-when-tunnelling

Answer (score 0):

### Simple remote browsing

If you'd like to browse the web locally as if you were sitting in front of a remote box:

```
$ ssh -X username@remote.example.com
```

then run Firefox **inside the remote terminal session**:

```
$ firefox https://test-ipv6.com/
```

Notice the usage of `-X` flag in the `ssh` command.
You can also do both steps in a single go, like shown below:

```
$ ssh -X username@remote.example.com firefox http://test-ipv6.com/
```

### Tunnelling a remote IP:port

If you have an application running remotely which exposes some sort of web frontend, you will be interested on exposing the remote IP:port as if it is a local IP:port. In this case, the `-L` option defines a correspondence between `localhost:localport` and `remotehost:remoteport`, as shown in the pseudo command below:

```
ssh -L localhost:localport:remotehost:remoteport remoteuser@remotehost
```

For example:

```
$ ssh -L 127.0.0.1:18080:internal.example.com:8080 username@router.example.com
```

then run Firefox **locally**:

```
$ firefox http://127.0.0.1:18080
```

In the example above, you are connecting via SSH onto `username@router.example.com`, and you are interested on a web frontend exposed at `internal.example.com:8080`. This remote IP:port will be exposed locally at `127.0.0.1:18080`.